# How to get itune unique id , of installed Apps

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios

I am developing app , which need to only list the ,

1-All installed app name with its unique itune id.

Ex- http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-status-device-activity/id401457165?mt=8

Here , "system-status-device-activity" is app in itune store , suppose I installed the app in my iphone/ipad .

Can any one help me , how to get that "id401457165" , programmatically ,menas by writing any code like:
NSStrng *myid = getItuneID();

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer NO. You can't get this info any other installed application. Even I don't think iTunes id is even exist in the binary file (.ipa). I think the iTunes id only exist on apple servers and they bind iTunes id with app bundle identifier.

Comment: Thanx @saursbh , I think you may know about "iHas" third party sdk . it is able to access that itune id , but it is not giving all installed app itune id. I think in that binary file(.ipa) that id is exist.